# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 cropping image

Tags: java, android

I have been using the library com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+ for my image cropping. Here I run into a problem, when I am  able to open my gallery, but when i select an image to crop my app crashed.
08-16 16:52:14.661 30951-909/com.myproj.blogapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                  Process:

```
com.myproj.blogapp, PID: 30951
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/media/ExifInterface;
                                                                      at com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.BitmapUtils.rotateBitmapByExif(BitmapUtils.java:85)
                                                                      at com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.BitmapLoadingWorkerTask.doInBackground(BitmapLoadingWorkerTask.java:92)
                                                                      at com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.BitmapLoadingWorkerTask.doInBackground(BitmapLoadingWorkerTask.java:26)
                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.media.ExifInterface" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myproj.blogapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                      at com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.BitmapUtils.rotateBitmapByExif(BitmapUtils.java:85) 
                                                                      at com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.BitmapLoadingWorkerTask.doInBackground(BitmapLoadingWorkerTask.java:92) 
                                                                      at com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.BitmapLoadingWorkerTask.doInBackground(BitmapLoadingWorkerTask.java:26) 
                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) 
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                                                    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.media.ExifInterface
                                                                      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                            ... 10 more
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

java

```
package com.myproj.blogapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class SetupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton mSetupImageBtn;
    private EditText mNameField;
    private Button mSubmitBtn;

    private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup);

        mSetupImageBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.setupImageBtn);
        mNameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameField);
        mSubmitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitBtn);

        mSetupImageBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();

            CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                    .start(this);
        }

        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);


            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

                mSetupImageBtn.setImageURI(resultUri);

            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using multidex?

Comment: yeah its enabled

Comment: ahh today's a beautiful day. thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Add to your app build.gradle dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:26.+'
```

Take note of the `compileSdkVersion`. I'm using 26, thats why i have '26.+'